# Unable to use cordova-plugin-websql on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I'm writing a Cordova app with Visual Studio 2015.

After installing the cordova-plugin-websql plugin I get a build error.

> Your project.json doesn't list 'win10' as a targeted runtime. You should add '"win10": { }' inside your "runtimes" section in your project.json, and then re-run NuGet restore.
>
> [C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\mySOlution\myProject\CordovaApp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.NuGet.targets 211

I tried to open and upgrade SQLite.Proxy.csproj to target Winodws 8.1 (also Windows 10) but with exactly same results.

Any idea?

Comment: I ran into the same problem with a different plugin. After removing the plugin I still had to create a new solution to get rid of the error. I was lucky because I did not have to move much files. Did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: No. I need to store just few data, so I choose localStorage instead.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be an open issue with that plugin and Windows 10.  However, there are actually some more powerful alternatives that may be worth considering instead of the WebSQL plugin that also enable "no limit" storage on Android and iOS instead of the 50mb you'll be limited to with WebSQL on iOS for example.

For example, check out https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage that should work with Windows 10. You simply need to use the Windows-x86 or Windows-x64 platforms in VS since it uses C++ code (and thus is also faster thant the WebSQL plugin).

Comment: They split the cordova-sqlite-storage repo into mutliple ones. The Windows 10 plugin is now available on https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-ext